# Android: ActionBarCompat (Support library)

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

i have a problem.
I'm using support library for my app.
I add some Action items on my ActionBar by XML-file.

From docs:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

It works. But the item stays on all fragments.

I need use different action items in ActionBar.

I created a few menu-files and tried to use them on different frаgments, but it doesn't work.

I see only the first Action item from class extends ActionBarActivity.

From fragment:

```
public class Foods extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener 
...
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.showinfo_menu, menu);
            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
            // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
            searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search));
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found my mistake.

If you want ActionBar items of fragmets to work, you should add it:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
```